# Fix for "certificate not found" for iOS Distribution when exporting from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

When archiving i kept receiving a certificate not found, even though i downloaded the certificate from my developer.apple area, and installed in keychain.

This problem is I am unable to export (ie - keychain isnt recognizing my provisioning/distribution certificate); but i am able to build an run in Developer mode through my Dev.apple account.

Answer (score 0):

While the Cert was in keychain, it was being installed as a "login" cert by default.

Adding the Certificate as a "SYSTEM" certificate solved the problem.

Instead of double click;

Keychain -> IMPORT

Select file && Choose Destination: System before importing the certificate, once in system - Try Again for xcode.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think this is right. I can export just fine, and all my certificates are under "login".

Comment: My certificate under login would not be recognized with Xcode. When I added it to system, Xcode recognized it. Asked to allow its explicit use, then it worked.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know why that would be, since my certificates are under login and Xcode does recognize them. What I'm saying is: no one _else_ has to put their certificates under System, and you should not be advising this as a solution (even though it worked for you).

Comment: If no one else had to do this, they wouldnt have this problem. System Certs are used by programs, - like xcode. Likely it is a default mac security requirement. As I took my MAC out of the box, loaded up Xcode, and opened a git folder. So if out of the box your XCODE cant see your cert on your login chain, add it to system, so your programs can use the Cert. Which makes sense - since its a system based cert beingused by programs, not login.  If you tweaked your security settings, this wont be an issue. Also since its YOUR certificate, there is NO HARM by adding to your system keychain

Comment: My point is that _you_ may be having some sort of larger permissions issue here, which other people do _not_ have, and you should be worried about that rather than being satisfied with your "solution" to the problem. - Are you running as an admin user? I've never _not_ run as an admin user so I have no idea whether that would matter.

Comment: Admin user, brand new mac. Nothing modified, just used for this really. Took it out of the box, made a nick account, and Viola, Mac problems :)